# Enviar el name del boton pulsado para enviar un formulario via javascript

Tags: javascript, php

tengo una duda, tengo un formulario que tiene dos botones de submit. Y depende de con cual se pulse va a hacer una cosa u otra. La cosa esta en que necesito mandar una alerta de confirmar el envió del formulario. Agregue el evento para que aparezca el modal, pero el usar e.preventDefault(), me hace perder el name del botón, por lo cual no se que botón fue pulsado.

Entonces como hago para poner un modal de confirmación y aparte mantener en el envió del formulario, el name del botón que lo envía.

Es algo así el codigo:

```
<form id="formulario-enviar" method="POST" action="direccion.php">
   <input type="submit" name="boton1" />
   <input type="submit" name="boton2" />
</form>

 document.getElementById('formulario-enviar').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     Swal.fire({
            icon: "warning",
            title: "Eliminar",
            text: `¿Está seguro que desea eliminar la información?`,
            showCancelButton: true,
            cancelButtonColor: '#838383',
            confirmButtonColor: '#E2001A',
            confirmButtonText: 'Si, eliminalo',
            buttonsStyling: true,
            cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
            footer: "Si se elimina, no se podra recuperar el registro",
        }).then((result) => {
             if (result.isConfirmed) {
                  document.getElementById('formulario-enviar').submit();
             }
         })
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para identificar que disparo el evento `submit` del formulario, podes utlizar la proiedad [`submitter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter) del [`SubmitEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent)

> La propiedad `submitter` de solo lectura que se encuentra en la interfaz de `SubmitEvent` especifica el botón de envío u otro elemento que se invocó para enviar el formulario.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('formulario-enviar').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.submitter.name)
});
```

```html
<form id="formulario-enviar" method="POST" action="direccion.php">
  <input type="submit" name="boton1" />
  <input type="submit" name="boton2" />
</form>
```

Comment: Otra opción sería usar inputs tipo `button` normal y llamar a la función de enviar el formulario pasándole un identificador único para cada botón, y luego se hace el envío desde JS al aceptar el modal, de esa forma tampoco hace falta el `preventDefault` puesto que no hay evento de envío, solo un click en un botón :P

Comment: @Benito-B Entiendo, si lo hago con botones de tipo normal usando el id, puedo identificar que botón fue pulsado antes de enviar el formulario. ¿Cómo enviaría esa información junto con el formulario al archivo PHP que va a recibir el formulario?

Comment: @Benito-B Porque donde de verdad necesito distinguirlo es en el archivo que recibe el form.

Comment: Hola @JoseLopez. Podes resolverlo de muchas formas, por ejemplo, agregando un `<input type="hidden" name="boton"/>` y al enviar le estables el valor que corresponda.

Comment: Ok, gracias :) .

Answer (score 1):

Quisiera ofrecer una alternativa a la ya excelente respuesta de Marcos.

[HTML Datasets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

La propiedad de sólo lectura `dataset` de la interfaz `HTMLElement` ofrece una manera de leer y escribir atributos personalizados en los elementos.

Puedes escribir el nombre del botón, un id o los datos que creas que serán útiles para tu aplicación.

Usar la propiedad es tan sencillo como:

```
<input type="submit" id="primerBoton" data-nombre-boton="boton1" />
<input type="submit" id="segundoBoton" data-nombre-boton="boton2" />
```

Para extraer los datos:

```
const boton = document.getElementById("primerBoton");
const nombreBoton = boton.dataset.nombreBoton;
console.log(nombreBoton); // "boton1"
```

Si deseas incorporarlo a tu código.

```js
document.getElementById('formulario-enviar').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.submitter.name);
  console.log(e.submitter.dataset.nombreBoton);
  });
```

```html
<form id="formulario-enviar" method="POST" action="direccion.php">
  <input type="submit" data-nombre-boton="boton1 via data" name="boton1" />
  <input type="submit" data-nombre-boton="boton2 via data" name="boton2" />
</form>
```

Yo lo uso en caso que tenga que poner información que mi aplicación utilizará y que no cabe en propiedades de HTMLElement estándar, como `name` o `id`